# Conditional formatting won't update without double clicking cell in target range

Tags: excel, vba

I've made an excel timetable with days and times as columns and rows, respectively. Ive created a conditional format to highlight the current day, time and corresponding cell.

When the current time ticks over into a new 1/2 hour interval the conditional format doesn't automatically change and instead just goes blank as though it's stopped working (and yes I've got 'Calculation Options' in the 'Formulas' tab set to 'Automatic').

When I double click the reference cell (e.g. the time row corresponding to the current time) and click off it, it works. This is obviously not ideal - any suggestions would be great.

I have seen this issue raised but haven't had any satisfactory solutions.

Comment: Formulas in Excel don't recalculate spontaneously - there needs to be some event (such as a changing input value) to trigger them.   If you want your workbook to update periodically then look into using `Application.OnTime` to trigger a recalculation.

Comment: @TimWilliams So I've included that line already where the formula updates the cell used in the conditional formatting formula. The problem is the conditional formatting itself doesn't seem to update. Is there a way to reference the conditional formatting rules and update them?

Comment: If you have code already which is supposed to trigger a refresh but doesn't, then it might help to include that in your question.